# Does Next.js Needs a Node Server Running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

How does Next.js SSR working exactly.

If I don't care SEO at all then I can use React right?
What if i care about SEO and don't want/need a node.js server in my background.

I have an API written in PHP. I tried in my local server to send requests from Next app to PHP Backend. In a real application do i have to create a Node.js backend in my server or is it enough to install Node and Npm only to install Next and it's dependencies?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any page that uses getServerSideProps, Next.js converts that page to a lambda function. You don't need a node server running 24/7 for hosting your application.

Also, if you don't use getServerSideProps, Next.js by default will pre-render your page, this page gets cached on a CDN.

So yes you can make API calls to your PHP backend, without the need for a setting up a nodejs server yourself.

Hope that answers your question.

Thanks

Comment: do you have more info on how Nextjs converts that page to a lambda function? Also if we have API routes don't we need a node server running?

Comment: And what Nextjs is doing with this lambda function? Self-hosting somewhere?